# How to get a return value for javascript function after .load()?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

So yesterday I discovered the possibility of calling another function after a load. Now, I am trying to get a php variable that is generated from the loaded page. Here is the code -- I think I'm just missing a few lines or so.

```
function compute(id)
{
    var qty=document.getElementById('qty'+id).value;
    $("#sub"+id).show();
    $("#sub"+id).load('subtotal.php?qty='+qty+'&cartid='+id, function (total) {
        document.getElementById('totalholder').value = total;
    });
}
```

This is the subtotal.php.

```
<?php
    require("connect.php");
    session_start();

    $qty=$_GET['qty'];
    $cartid=$_GET['cartid'];
    $id=$_SESSION['ID'];

    $query=mysql_query("update tblcart set quantity=$qty where CartID = $cartid and UserID=$id");
    mysql_query("update tblcart set subtotal=price*quantity where CartID = $cartid and UserID=$id");
    $x=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("Select Subtotal from tblcart where CartID = $cartid and UserID=$id"));
    $total=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("Select SUM(Subtotal) As Total from tblcart where UserID = $id"));
?>
<div id="<?php echo "sub".$cartid;?>" style="width:100%;float:left;">
<?php echo "Php ".number_format ( $x['Subtotal'], 2, '.', ','); ?>

</div>

<script>
    return (<?php $total; ?>);
</script>
```

I would want to return the php variable $total to the function to be able to use it after the load(). Help is much appreciated, and thank you in advanced! xx

Comment: i don't see an element with the id of "totalholder" in your new html, just a dynamic id.

Comment: Is the Js function written in the same file? (subtotal.php) If so you can echo $total in its place.

Comment: also you are missing the type tag on your <script>, should be <script type="text/javascript" > but essentially you are returning load into this container $("#sub"+id)

Comment: dandavis, the totalholder is located in my index.php

Comment: john, no the js is located in my index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

This is what you are missing

> .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned
>   data. This means that most uses of the method can be quite simple:

This could be shorted

```
document.getElementById('totalholder').value = total;
```

to

```
 $('#totalholder').val(total);
```

but, imagine this in its own script tag outside of the load function

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    return (<?php $total; ?>);
</script>
```

so you are just returning total to thin air.

you could do

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    alert(<?php $total; ?>);
</script>
```

but something like this is what you want

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
      $('#totalholder').val(<?php $total; ?>);
</script>
```

assuming you had an element #totalholder

UPDATE:

What I would do then is set the total in an element in the returned html, skip the JavaScript in the returned html, and then access it from the call back,

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is
>   fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set
>   to each DOM element in turn.

so somtehing like this in the returned html.

```
<input type="hidden" id="total" value="<?php echo $total; ?>"/>
```

and in the callback

```
    $("#sub"+id).load('subtotal.php?qty='+qty+'&cartid='+id, function () {
            /*The callback is
fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set
to each DOM element in turn.*/
            if($(this).prop('id') == 'total'){
                var total = $(this).val();
            }
        });
```

Just as a note, I don't usually use .load() and stick mainly to $.post, $.get etc..

Comment: Thank you! I've achieved my goal here, although I persisted on using .show and .load() again after the first load. But still, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with just a simple `$.get()`:

```
function compute(id)
{
    $.get('subtotal.php', {
        qty: $('#qty' + id).val(),
        cartid: id
    }, function(data) {
        $('#sub' + id).text(data.subtotal).show();
        $('totalholder').val(data.total);
    });
}
```

Then, the PHP returns a JSON encoded body:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'subtotal' => $x['Subtotal'],
    'total' => $total['Total'],
));
```